# How to get changes only, of two xml files in c# context?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, compare

Im setting up an XML Translator and before this step, I have to compare two XML Files, filter out the changes or entrys that are new and save only the changes in a new file.

With `XmlDiffPatch` I was able to compare the two files and save it in a DiffGram format. But when I patch the `diffGramFile` and the `originalFile`, the output is just like my `originalFile` so I win nothing out of it. Is there a way to delete duplicates of two files or like only save the changes?

This is my code to generate a diffGram and Patch it up.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file1 = "C:\\temp\\test.xml";
            string file2 = "C:\\temp\\test2.xml";
            string output = "C:\\temp\\output.xml";
            string finaloutput = "C:\\temp\\final.xml";

            //DiffXmlStrict(file1, file2);

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings);

            GenerateDiffGram(file1, file2, writer);
            PatchUp(file2, output, finaloutput);
        }

        public static void GenerateDiffGram(string finalFile, string originalFile, XmlWriter diffGramWriter)
        {
            XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |
                                             XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces |
                                             XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
            bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(originalFile, finalFile, false, diffGramWriter);
            diffGramWriter.Close();
        }
        public static void PatchUp(String originalFile, String diffGramFile, String OutputFile)
        {
            XmlDocument sourceDoc = new XmlDocument(new NameTable());
            sourceDoc.Load(originalFile);
            XmlTextReader diffgramReader = new XmlTextReader(diffGramFile);

            XmlPatch xmlPatch = new XmlPatch();
            xmlPatch.Patch(sourceDoc, diffgramReader);


            XmlTextWriter output = new XmlTextWriter(OutputFile, Encoding.Unicode);
            sourceDoc.Save(output);
            output.Close();

        }
```

Input files:
File 1: test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core-1.2-transitional.xsd">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" date="2016-02-08T14:15:00Z">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1001" resname="ErrorCode.1001" >
                <source>Call not implemented.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1002" resname="ErrorCode.1002" >
                <source>Cannot copyy %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1003" resname="ErrorCode.1003" >
                <source>Cannot create all parameters for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1004" resname="ErrorCode.1004" >
                <source>Cannot create %e for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1005" resname="ErrorCode.1005" >
                <source>Cannot delete all parameters for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1006" resname="ErrorCode.1006" >
                <source>Cannot find %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1007" resname="ErrorCode.1007" >
                <source>Cannot get %s name.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1008" resname="ErrorCode.1008" >
                <source>Cannot get object.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1009" resname="ErrorCode.1009" >
                <source>Cannot get parameter.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1010" resname="ErrorCode.1010" >
                <source>Cannot load document for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1011" resname="ErrorCode.1011" >
                <source>Cannot unload document for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1012" resname="ErrorCode.1012" >
                <source>Cannot reload document for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

File 2: test2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core-1.2-transitional.xsd">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" date="2016-02-08T14:15:00Z">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1001" resname="ErrorCode.1001" >
                <source>Call not implemented.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1002" resname="ErrorCode.1002" >
                <source>Cannot copy %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1003" resname="ErrorCode.1003" >
                <source>Cannot create all parameters for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1004" resname="ErrorCode.1004" >
                <source>Cannot create %e for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1005" resname="ErrorCode.1005" >
                <source>Cannot delete all parameters for %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1006" resname="ErrorCode.1006" >
                <source>Cannot find %s.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1007" resname="ErrorCode.1007" >
                <source>Cannot get %s name.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1008" resname="ErrorCode.1008" >
                <source>Cannot get object.</source>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit  datatype="plaintext" id="ErrorCode.1009" resname="ErrorCode.1009" >
                <source>Cannot get parameter.</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

and `finaloutput` File equals File 1..

hope for some help.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all you want is a delta. In that case, you should not patch the original file (which is the over-complete one anyway, so it already includes the delta), but use the diffGramFile instead. It already contains the delta, right? If needs be, simply apply an xslt transform to bring it into the desired shape (xliff 1.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication131
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_XML1 = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string INPUT_XML2 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_XML = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(INPUT_XML1);
            XElement body1 = doc1.Descendants("body").FirstOrDefault();
            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(INPUT_XML2);
            XElement body2 = doc2.Descendants("body").FirstOrDefault();

            var query1 = (from d1 in body1.Elements()
                         join d2 in body2.Elements() on d1.ToString() equals d2.ToString() into p
                         from d2 in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new { d1 = d1, d2 = p == null ? null : d2 })
                         .Where(x => x.d2 == null)
                         .Select(x => x.d1)
                         .ToList();


            var query2 = (from d2 in body2.Elements()
                          join d1 in body1.Elements() on d2.ToString() equals d1.ToString() into p
                          from d1 in p.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new { d2 = d2, d1 = p == null ? null : d1 })
                          .Where(x => x.d1 == null)
                          .Select(x => x.d2)
                          .ToList();

            XElement newBody = new XElement("body", query1);
            newBody.Add(query2);
            body1.ReplaceWith(newBody);
            doc1.Save(OUTPUT_XML);

        }
    }




}
```

Comment: that worked well to me, still the second query (query2) is not necessary because it gives me the unchanged value back, so there are two entrys for my changed entry in the output.

Comment: When I tested I remove different items from each list.  There must be a slight difference in the two files to put the same item back.  The code is testing the entire element so something is different (it could be spacing or lowercase/uppercase differences).