# Comparing with two XML file and get the difference between them in anew XML file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need help please I have two XML files,They have the same id("name")I want to get difference between them.
if I have extra nodes in Xml file_1, so it will go to diff. xml file according to only id.
I have wrote som code but I don't know how it will be if; I know we can do in Microsoft Diff and Patch tool but I want a different code:
here is my code:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
           //fields
         const string XML1 = @"File_1.xml";
         const string XML2 = @"File_2.xml";
         const string ResultFile = @"ResultFile.xml";
         XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
         doc1.Load(XML1);
         XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
         doc2.Load(XML2);

         for(var d = 0; d < doc1.SelectNodes("root/data").Count; d++)
         {
             var child = doc1.SelectNodes("root/data")[d];
            if (I don't know …..) {

           }
         }
```

**XML fil_1**

```
<root>
  <data name="senChangePassword" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Byt lösenord</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="senChangesWereSuccessfullySaved" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Ändringarna är sparade</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="senChangeUserSettings" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Ändra uppgifter</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="senCompareWith" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Jämför</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="senCreatedQuestions" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Skapade frågor</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
</root>
```

** XML file_2**

```
<root>
  <data name="senChangePassword" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Change Password</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="senChangesWereSuccessfullySaved" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Saved changes</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02  Jessica</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="senCompareWith" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Compare</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
</root>
```

XML file_result

```
<root>
  <data name="senChangeUserSettings" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Ändra uppgifter</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="senCreatedQuestions" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Skapade frågor</value>
    <comment>Sprint 02 - Jessica</comment>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885510/how-to-get-only-changes-of-two-xml-files-in-c-sharp-context/57886190#57886190

Comment: It is difficult code for me , it is advanced and I don't anderstand xml.linq, I need a code withe just " using system.xml" . I want to compare only node id not space or inner text.

Comment: This is quite a challenging problem to solve. Consider investing in a solution like DeltaXML rather than trying to tackle this yourself.

Comment: but in your link code , result file will be both files for my xml files, I don't need that. Can you change in your code to get the same result file, because I have no idea about linq.

Comment: The solution is much simpler in Xml Linq using a left outer join.

Comment: How it will be please! Which Changes should be

Answer (score 1):

Simple version (if you don't care about performance or memory size):

```
using System.Linq;

// ....
var nodes1 = doc1.SelectNodes("root/data");
var children1 = new List<XmlNode>();
int i = 0;
foreach(XmlNode a in nodes1) { children1[i++] = a; }
var nodes2 = doc2.SelectNodes("root/data");
var children2 = new List<XmlNode>();
i = 0;
foreach(XmlNode b in nodes2) { children2[i++] = b; }
var result = new List<XmlNode>();

for(var d = 0; d < children1.Count; d++)
         {
             var child = children1[d];
             var match = children2.FirstOrDefault(x=>
                 XElement.Parse(x.OuterXml).ToString() == XElement.Parse(child.OuterXml).ToString());
            if (match == null) {
               result.Add(child);
           }
         }
```

and dump result nodes into result file as best you see fit

Comment: You might also want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442123/in-c-how-do-i-convert-a-xmlnode-to-string-with-indentation-without-looping for understanding the duality between XmlNode and its matching string. It's almost the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for answer                                                                               there are tow  wrongs in code this row:                                          var result = List<XmlNode>();                                                         and in this row:                                                                                var match = children2.FirstOrDefault(…...); the fel is XMLNodeList does not contain a defination for (FirstOrDefault). What should I do here,

Comment: you need to add the namespace "using System.Linq;"

Comment: I have provided it  but it does not work. what shoild do please

Comment: Thanks for the note @Osama - that's what I get for writing code on the fly in stackoverflow. shame on me :o) 
hope this helps...